# Proving functional's continuity

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove that functional $f:C[a,b]\to \mathbb{R},\ f(x)=\int_a^bx^2(t)dt$ is continuous.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: But this isn't linear.

Comment: H yeah, my bad, did not read carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\|y-x\| < 1.$ Then $$|f(y)-f(x)|\le \int_a^b|y^2-x^2| = \int_a^b|y-x|\,|y+x|$$ $$ \le \|y+x\|\|y-x\|(b-a)\le (\|x\|+1)\|y-x\|(b-a) \to 0$$ as $y\to x.$ This shows $f$ is continuous at $x.$

Comment: Is it necessary to assume x,y in $C[a,b]$?

Comment: According to your problem, $C[a,b]$ is the domain of $f$.

Comment: Its not my problem; I just dont see where it is used in this solution.

Comment: @gary I think the existence of the sup is where continuity is used. You can probably get away with weaker conditions though (maybe just $L^{\infty}$).

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Cant we just use sequential continuity : $ (f_n \rightarrow f) \rightarrow (T(f_n) \rightarrow T(f))$?

Comment: It looks like this functional is continuous on $L^p([a,b]), 2\le p \le \infty.$

Answer (score 0):

We can use sequential continuity, i.e.,we an show T(f) is continuous by showing $f_n \right arrow f$  ,i.e., $|| f_n -f|| \rightarrow 0  \rightarrow [T(f_n)-T(f) \rightarrow 0] $

Let $f_n \rightarrow f $, so that $||f_n-f || < \epsilon$. Then $$|T(f_n)-T(f)| = \int (f_n)^2 -f^2 \rightarrow 0$$.

If $f_n \rightarrow f$, then $Sup_{[a,b]} |f_n-f|< \epsilon$, so that $$\int (f_n^2-f^2) \leq \epsilon \int(f+g) \rightarrow 0 $$ , since $(f+g)$ is in $C[a,b]$, so that $f_n+f$ is bounded in $[a,b]$ by, say $M$. Then $\int f_n^2 -f^2 \leq \int e(M^3/3) \rightarrow 0 $